# Unable to load a file with [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile]?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

Have a file incorporated in the "Supporting files" in Xcode called: `taxrates.csv`.

```
NSString *fileString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:@"taxrates.csv" encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
NSLog(@"%@",fileString); // <-- just displays null
```

Comment: I bet that `error` argument could be useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because the current directory of the application is not the path of the application, instead it is the path of the containing UUID folder.

To fix, try using `[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"taxrates" ofType:@"csv"]` to get the path of the file instead of using a raw string.

Comment: @jdl if the file exists in your target, it should not return null.

Comment: @jdl glad to help. Just remember to accept & up vote the answer :)